# SQL Time Zone Conversion for datetime2

Tags: sql, timezone

I want to convert a datetime2 field from an Azure SQL Table to a given Time Zone (in this case 'Mountain Standard Time')

```
SELECT [Created] AT TIME ZONE 'Mountain Standard Time' FROM MyTable
```

Returned a result of format "03/26/2018 17:00:11 -06:00", this is a datetimeoffset which cannot be directly CAST or CONVERTED to a datetime or datetime2

The following gives me the answer I need but surely there must be a less verbose method

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, CONVERT(datetimeoffset,[Created] AT TIME ZONE 'Mountain Standard Time'), [Created]), [Created]) AS CreatedLocalTime FROM MyTable
```